# document.body.span javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, html

I would like to call a function when any of my `<span>` elements is clicked.
I wish I could do this:

```
document.body.span.onClick = function(){
// do something
}
```

Can someone show me the right way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
     spans[i].onClick = function() {
       // do something
     }
}
```

You should really use jQuery for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
   var allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

   for (var i = 0; i < allSpans.length; i++) {
        allSpans[i].onclick = spanClickHandler;
   }
}

function spanClickHandler(e) {
      // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
var spansCount = spans.length;
for(var i=0; i<spansCount; i++){
  spans[i].onClick = function(){
   //YOUR_CODE
  }
}
```

P.S: Why not take a look at [jQuery JS Framework](http://jquery.com/) and see if you can start using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and write.

```
function myFunction(){
    // Do your thing.
}

$(window).load(function () {
    $('span').click(myFunction);
});
```

Yes, you just need to download the jQuery js file and include it at the top of the page to make this work. I highly recommend learning jQuery as it can simplify a lot of things. You can mix jQuery style code and "regular" JS too, without problem.